# Reading a file content does not raise exception if the file is not present

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to read a file as follows and I want to log an error if the file does not exist. So I wrote the following code. But this code does not go into the except block at all. I don't have the file for sure.

```
    DEFAULT_ROLE_PROPERTIES = '/tmp/role.properties'

    try:            
        self.role_properties = os.environ.get('VAULT_ROLE_PROPERTIES', DEFAULT_ROLE_PROPERTIES)
        with open(self.role_properties, 'r') as rolefp:
            cfg.readfp(rolefp)
        self.role_id = cfg.get('region', 'role_id')
    except Exception as msg:
        self.log.error("Unable to read role properties")
```

I am not sure what is wrong with the syntax here. The above code is in an init function (constructor) could that be the issue?

```
ls /tmp/role.properties
ls: cannot access /tmp/role.properties: No such file or directory
```

Comment: except `FileNotFoundError` so that your code doesn't catch things you don't want it to

Comment: If the file does not exist, the `open()` call will certainly raise an exception.

Comment: It is not going in Except block at all.

Comment: Well, what does it do? What if you `print(self.role_properties, rolefp, cfg, self.role_id)`?

Comment: can you show us the result of this: print(os.listdir('/temp')), i already tried your code and it works as it should and printed "Unable to read role properties"

Answer (score 0):

You could use [os.path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) to check that the path exists (first) before proceeding with getting environment/other attributes

Sample code:

```
import os.path
os.path.exists('tmp/role.properties/')
```

If you were checking to see if a particular file was present, and valid (not empty) you could use [os.stat](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat)

```
try:
    if os.stat(filename).st_size > 0:
       print "file present"
    else:
       print "file present but empty"
except OSError:
    print "No file"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @aaj did you fix your error with the help of my answer? If so could you vote and/or accept?